# Add the missing Object's by comparing Two array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, charts, apexcharts

I am trying to plot a chart to display sales comparison by year for the brands, below are the two arrays of sales by year.

```
var current_year = [
  {
    total: 12941.17,
    comapanyName: "Samsung",
    year: "2021"
  },
  {
    total: 17946.87,
    comapanyName: "Haier",
    year: "2021"
  },
  {
    total: 3832.36,
    comapanyName: "Beetel",
    year: "2021"
  },
  {
    total: 12528,
    comapanyName: "Celkon",
    year: "2021"
  }
];
var last_year = [
  {
    total: 427805.51,
    comapanyName: "Samsung",
    year: "2020"
  },
  {
    total: 77576.33,
    comapanyName: "Godrej",
    year: "2020"
  },
  {
    total: 53389.02,
    comapanyName: "Beetel",
    year: "2020"
  },
  {
    total: 100748.49,
    comapanyName: "Celkon",
    year: "2020"
  },
  {
    total: 4534.19,
    comapanyName: "FORD",
    year: "2020"
  },
  {
    total: 5.05,
    comapanyName: "Voltas",
    year: "2020"
  }
];
```

Since some company names are missing in respective arrays I'm not able to plot the chart as expected. I need help in adding the missing company name in respective array with year, name and total.
Similar to this chart [https://apexcharts.com/react-chart-demos/line-charts/data-labels/](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

Expectation -

1. company "FORD" is present in last_year but missing in current_year array, Add the "FORD" Object in current_year array
   Example = [{total:0, comapnyName:'FORD', year:2021}]
2. company "Haier" is present in current_year but missing in last_year array, Add the "Haier" in last_year array
   Example = [{total:0, comapnyName:"Haier", year:2020}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is an example that can help you

```
var current_year = [
  {
    total: 12941.17,
    comapanyName: "Samsung",
    year: "2021"
  },
  {
    total: 17946.87,
    comapanyName: "Haier",
    year: "2021"
  },
  {
    total: 3832.36,
    comapanyName: "Beetel",
    year: "2021"
  },
  {
    total: 12528,
    comapanyName: "Celkon",
    year: "2021"
  }
];
var last_year = [
  {
    total: 427805.51,
    comapanyName: "Samsung",
    year: "2020"
  },
  {
    total: 77576.33,
    comapanyName: "Godrej",
    year: "2020"
  },
  {
    total: 53389.02,
    comapanyName: "Beetel",
    year: "2020"
  },
  {
    total: 100748.49,
    comapanyName: "Celkon",
    year: "2020"
  },
  {
    total: 4534.19,
    comapanyName: "FORD",
    year: "2020"
  },
  {
    total: 5.05,
    comapanyName: "Voltas",
    year: "2020"
  }
];
```

```
        const currentYearData = {};

        for (const item of current_year) {
          currentYearData[item.comapanyName] = true;
        }

        for (const item of last_year) {
          if (!currentYearData.hasOwnProperty(item.comapanyName) && item.comapanyName) {
            // Company exists in last_year but not in current_year
            current_year.push({ total: 0, companyName: item.comapanyName, year: "2021" });
          }
        }

        for (const item of current_year) {
          if (!last_year.find(c => c.comapanyName === item.comapanyName) && item.comapanyName) {
            // Company exists in current_year but not in last_year
            last_year.push({ total: 0, companyName: item.comapanyName, year: "2020" });
          }
        }

        console.log(current_year);
        console.log(last_year);
```

Comment: Thank you @Hichaaaaam this helps, but end result of last and current year length should be equal.

Comment: I have updated code, please check it